# Question about Product Topology

Tags: general-topology

I know if X = {a,b} and Y = {c,d,e},  then X $\times$ Y = {(a,c),(a,d),(a,e),(b,c),(b,d),(b,e)}

However,I am confusing when seeing the follow example:

> Take the topology $\tau$ = {$\varnothing$, {a, b}, {a} } on X = {a,
>   b}.
>  Then the product topology on X $\times$ X is :
>   {$\varnothing$, X $\times$  X, {(a, a)}, {(a, a), (a, b)}, {(a, a),
>   (b, a)}, {(a, a), (a, b), (b, a)} } where the last open set in the
>   list is not in the basis.

My Questions:
1. I think X $\times$ X should be {$\varnothing$, ({a,b},{a,b}) , ({a,b},{a}) , ({a},{a,b}) ,({a},{a}) }, 
   I know the result is wrong, but I don't know what am I missing? 
2. Why  {(a, a), (a, b), (b, a) is not in the basis for X $\times$  X?

**[UPDATE]**
The example is from http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MT4522/Lectures/L15.html
[image]

The result [except $\varnothing$ and X $\times$ X, each element is enclosed by curly brackets, not round brackets] is obviously different from @kahen's answer below.
So I really hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 3):

1. No. $X \times X = \{(a,a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b)\}$. $\emptyset$ is an element of $\tau$, not of $X$.
2. Please clarify. You mean that $\{(a,a),(a,b),(b,a)\}$ isn't a basic open set according to the definition of the product topology? This is hardly a surprise. For example we have open disks in $\mathbb R^2$ which certainly are not basic open sets w.r.t. to the product topology.